# JavaScript regex using strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use strings as the 'find' in a JS regex?

i.e.:

```
var find = ["a", "b", "c"];
var string = "abcdefghijkl";
```

Now, I want to replace all the elements of the array find, with a blank string ( `" "` ), using regular expressions. How can I do this?

I mean, using `.replace(/find[i]/g, "")` in a loop wouldn't work.

So, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically create regex with the built-in RegExp object.

```
var find = ["a", "b", "c"];
var re = new RegExp( find.join("|"), "g" ); // <- /a|b|c/g
var string = "abcdefghijkl";

string = string.replace(re, "");

alert(string); // <- defghijkl
​
```

Comment: Don't need to use the wrapping parens here - just `RegExp( find.join("|") )` will work fine.

Comment: While this will work for these simplified array contents, it will have bugs if the an item contains regex characters without escaping them.

Comment: @Jason in this case you can use something like preg_quote (from php.js): 
 
`str = (str+'').replace(/([\\\.\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!<>\|\:])/g, '\\$1');`

Answer (score 0):

Why don;t you use just

```
.replace(find[i], "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the expressions one at a time (for exampe if they are too complex to just concatentate into a singe expression), you create Regexp objects in a loop like this:

```
var find = ["a", "b", "c"];
var string = "abcdefghijkl";

for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
  var re = new Regexp(find[i], "g");
  string = string.replace(re, "");
}
```